# echo drop down menu onto a page

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a drop down menu with two options in html, I also created a PHP script that checks what option from the drop down menu has been selected and based on the selection executes a mysql query to fetch data from database.

But I am also trying to echo out a new drop down menu with the results obtained from database and that is where the I am struggling because no errors are diaplayed but also no drop down menu is 'echoed' out onto the page.

HTML:

```
<?php require "course.php" ?>

            <select id="workshop" name="workshop" onchange="return test();">
                <option value="">Please select a Workshop</option>
                <option value="Forex">Forex</option>
                <option value="BinaryOptions">Binary Options</option>
            </select>
```

PHP code:

```
   $form['workshop'] = $_POST['workshop'];
$form['forex'] = $_POST['Forex'];
$form['binary'] = $_POST['Binary'];


//Retrieve Binary Workshops 
if($form['workshop'] == 'Forex'){
    $sql2 = "SELECT id, course, location FROM courses WHERE course LIKE '%Forex%' OR  course LIKE '&forex%'";
        $query2 = mysqli_query($link, $sql2);
            echo "<select id='Forex' name='Forex' style='display: none'>";
                while($result2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2)){

                    echo "<option value=''>".$result2['course']."</option>";

                }
                echo "</select>";
                echo '</br>';


    }
```

Could someone point out a mistake I am doing or perhaps suggest where I could look for answers

Comment: It would be good if you mention error you are facing

Comment: There are no errors as I mentioned, The problem is there is the drop down menu does not appear at all

Comment: Eww inline HTML code. Did you check if the `mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2)` actually returns something?

Comment: Are you sure that $query2  has a value ?

Comment: yep i used print_r() function which clearley shows the results obtained from db, but as soon as i add all the echo bits to display drop down menu it does now return anything

Comment: note: `style='display: none'`

Comment: @Viridis Your the man totally forgotten about it many thx it works just fine now

Comment: Awesome :). It's things like this that make you go crazy, till you find out its just a super silly mistake haha.

Comment: yep i spend some time on it now and yet again it turns out to be a small mistake thx you much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

you said `$query2` is displaying value in print_r.so the only mistake i find in your code is display:none .

remove `display:none`

```
echo "<select id='Forex' name='Forex' style='display: none'>";
```

----------------------------------------------------------------------^

Comment: Yep as @Viridis Mentioned in comments this was the actual issue. Thank to you guys